# using openfda.brand_name.exact:"Tylenol" case sensitive

Tags: openfda

I have recently come across `openfda.brand_name.exact`. It is getting the results where the brand name has to match exactly, i.e. also case sensitive. For example, the query

[api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name.exact:"infants%20Tylenol"&limit=30](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name.exact:"infants%20Tylenol"&limit=30)

gives results but if i change the brand name to "infants tylenol" (small t), it won't return any results. Is there any way to query for exact `brand_name`s, but with case in-sensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, the `brand_name.exact` query term is case-sensitive.

You can search on `brand_name` instead of `brand_name.exact` to construct case-insensitive queries. For example, these queries are case-insensitive:

1. [`openfda.brand_name:"infants tylenol"`](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22infants%20tylenol%22)
2. [`openfda.brand_name:"infants Tylenol"`](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22infants%20Tylenol%22)
3. [`openfda.brand_name:"tylenol regular strength"`](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22tylenol%20regular%20strength%22)
4. [`openfda.brand_name:"TYLENOL Regular Strength"`](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22TYLENOL%20Regular%20Strength%22)